# How do resistive type fuel level sensors work?

Tags: resistors, sensor

Resistive type fuel level sensors which are used in fuel storage tanks(such as those at fuel stations) comprise of 2 visible parts; dual probe rods and a connecting float.

When the float is at the very bottom the output of the sensor is Vmin(possibly ~0V) and as the float progressively approaches the top the output increases upto Vmax(possibly ~Vsupp).

I would like to understand how these sensors work possibly by a simple circuit model?

For example:
XM/XT 66400 Series Continuous Level Transmitter(**note the dual rod/probes**)
[image]

Comment: There are many techniques for this. Can you show a photo or application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://kodiakcontrols.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/gems_xm66400_xm36490.pdf) says:

> These rugged transmitters are designed for tanks up to 18 feet (549 cm) in depth.
>   Heavy duty stems resist turbulence, and float options accommodate liquids with
>   minimum specific gravity as low as 0.53. **Standard resolution is 1/2 inch**; higher
>   resolutions are available on request. [Emphasis mine.]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1rHWN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The innards.*

The clue is in the 1/2" resolution that the sensor is using reed switches spaced at 1/2" intervals. The magnetic float is big enough to ensure that at lease one switch will be on at any position and it can be expected that there will be overlap in transitioning from one switch to the next.

> When the float is at the very bottom the output of the sensor is Vmin (possibly ~0 V) and as the float progressively approaches the top the output increases up to Vmax (possibly ~Vsupp).

The sensors come in a variety of options including 4 - 20 mA and 0 - 5 V output, for example. This means that there is a conditioning circuit in the head which converts the resistance scale to the required output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess based on the type your describing. The long probes with a magnetic float has a resistor tree wired in series with reed switches.

It has been a while since I pulled one down for repair but believe each resistor / reed was wired in parrellel. When the magnet was over a reed. That circuit was closed and the resistance of the sender decreased. Usually in the range of 10-220 ohms for the ones i dealt with.

Here is a link that has pictures to go with my explanation

https://www.reed-sensor.com/help-support/level-sensing-circuits/

A 500mm long sensor had 22 switches from memory. Its not linear but steps.

Some car manufacturers such as ford took this a bit furthur and included an amplifier on top of the reed switch sender to convert it to a voltage for the engine ecu.